# Is it a good idea to use Redis with MongoDB to improve performance of Code that uses lots of queries?

Tags: c++, mongodb, redis

I've written a C++ code that retrieves documents from MongoDB and sends them somewhere else. But The part that queries the database decreases the overall performance. Is it a good idea to move lots of documents to Redis and read them from there? what other performance-increasing solutions or techniques should I use?
P.S. I'm reading 1000 documents at a time.